# array_walk not changing value

Tags: php, array-walk

```
function values($id,$col)
{
     $vals = [1=>['name'=>'Lifting Heavy Boxes']];
     return $vals[$id][$col];
}
$complete = [1=>["id"=>"2","sid"=>"35","material_completed"=>"1","date"=>"2017-12-18"]];
$form = 'my_form';

array_walk($complete, function(&$d,$k) use($form) {
    $k = values($k, 'name').' ['.date('m/d/y',strtotime($d['date'])).'] ('.$form.')';
    echo 'in walk '.$k."\n";
});
print_r($complete);
```

the `echo` outputs:

`in walk Lifting Heavy Boxes [12/18/17] (my_form)`

the `print_r` outputs:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [sid] => 35
            [material_completed] => 1
            [date] => 2017-12-18
        )

)
```

I have another array walk that is very similar that is doing just fine. The only difference I can perceive between them is in the one that's working, the value $d is already a string before it goes through the walk, whereas in the one that's not working, $d is an array that is converted to a string inside the walk (successfully, but ultimately unsuccessfully).

Something I'm missing?

And here's the fixed version:

```
array_walk($complete, function(&$d,$k) use($form) {
    $d = values($k, 'name').' ['.date('m/d/y',strtotime($d['date'])).'] ('.$form.')';
});
```

That's what I was trying to do anyway. I wasn't *trying* to change the key. I was under the mistaken impression that to change the value you had to set the key to the new value.

Comment: you are at least missing a `'` as evidenced by the SO code highlighting

Comment: that's not the issue. that's just a translating to stack overflow issue.

Comment: I belive that but you should fix it so the questions gets more clear

Comment: i already did, thanks

Comment: @WorksforaLiving Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: since you are changing `$k` in your callback, did you try to have it passed as an reference, like changing signature to `&$k`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the key of the array inside the callback of [`array_walk()`](https://www.php.net/array_walk):

> Only the values of the `array` may potentially be changed; its structure cannot be altered, i.e., the programmer cannot add, unset or reorder elements. If the callback does not respect this requirement, the behavior of this function is undefined, and unpredictable.

This is also mentioned in the [first comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php#45380):

> It's worth nothing that array_walk can not be used to change keys in the array.
>   The function may be defined as (&$value, $key) but not (&$value, &$key).
>   Even though PHP does not complain/warn, it does not modify the key.

Comment: Thanks. I thought setting the key to the value inside the walk changed the value. I misunderstood the docs. That was the problem.